Problems logging into coinbase api with oauth2
I'm writing a Java Spring webapp that integrates with Coinbase API. I'm running into problems logging in with OAuth2. The docs don't seem to be complete, so I've run into some problems. I've been using https://docs.cdp.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/sign-in-with-coinbase-integration as my guide. The first step is to request access by calling "/oauth2/token". My first problem was that I got a 403 Forbidden error, but I finally got past that by adding "User-Agent" and "CB-VERSION" headers (not in the docs).
Now I get an HTML page back, which I guess I'm supposed to display to the user, but I had to add a "base" element to make the links in it work. That lets the user log into Coinbase, and I was thinking that this would lead to a call to my callback, but that's not happening.
BTW, I'm having to use "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" as my redirect URI as I'm working from localhost.
How do I move forward here?

You misunderstood the documentation. First, you have to redirect your user to the coinbase site (replace the parameter values with the ones for your registered app):
GET https://login.coinbase.com/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1532c63424622b6e9c4654e7f97ed40194a1547e114ca1c682f44283f39dfa49&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Foauth%2Fcallback&state=134ef5504a94&scope=wallet:user:read,wallet:accounts:read

Then coinbase will redirect to the value you have given with the parameter redirect_uri (here: https://example.com/oauth/callback). In this redirect you get a code:
GET https://example.com/oauth/callback?code=4c666b5c0c0d9d3140f2e0776cbe245f3143011d82b7a2c2a590cc7e20b79ae8&state=134ef5504a94

You then use this code login:
curl https://login.coinbase.com/oauth2/token \
  -X POST \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=4c666b5c0c0d9d3140f2e0776cbe245f3143011d82b7a2c2a590cc7e20b79ae8&client_id=1532c63424622b6e9c4654e7f97ed40194a1547e114ca1c682f44283f39dfa49&client_secret=3a21f08c585df35c14c0c43b832640b29a3a3a18e5c54d5401f08c87c8be0b20&redirect_uri=https://example.com/oauth/callback'

The response from coinbase contains the access token that you can use for further requests.

OK, so I have a login button and it currently calls a JS function which calls a Spring controller method. Sounds like you're saying the login button should go straight to that URL. Do I have that right?

Yes, it should directly go to coinbase.

Not sure about this statement: a session should be opened on the OAuth2 client (Spring backend configured with oauth2Login). So 1st request should be to Spring backend, which opens a session if none exists for the user agent and then redirects to Coinbase, which redirects back to Spring backend with a code (exchanged for tokens by Spring backend), which last redirects to the frontend.

When using a Spring OAuth2 client with oauth2Login, the 1st request should be to https://{your-spring-backend}/oauth2/authorization/{registration-id} where {registration-id} is a key for a registration with authorization_code flow. For instance, with the following Boot properties:
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          coinbase:
            authorization-uri: https://login.coinbase.com/oauth2/auth
            token-uri: https://login.coinbase.com/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user
        registration:
          my-bff:
            provider: coinbase
            client-id: ${oauth2-client-id}
            client-secret: ${oauth2-client-secret}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: wallet:user:read, wallet:accounts:read

I'd initiate users login at https://{my-domain}/oauth2/authorization/my-bff
It is important to start with a request to the Spring backend to ensure that a session is initiated. Tokens and security parameters used during the authorization code flow are saved in session.
As a reminder, here is the authorization code flow sequence:

Spring builds the authorization URI, and then redirects the user agent to the authorization server authorization endpoint (https://login.coinbase.com/oauth2/auth in the case of Coinbase), with all the required parameters (client credentials, redirect URI, state, and scope)
the authorization server runs its "login" flow (displays forms, checks for a "remember-me" cookie, or whatever)
once authentication is successful, the authorization server redirects the user agent to the OAuth2 client with an authorization code (https://{my-domain}/login/oauth2/code/my-bff in the case of the conf above)
the client calls the authorization server token endpoint to exchange the code for tokens (https://login.coinbase.com/oauth2/token in the case of Coinbase)

But for step 1 to happen (Spring redirecting to Coinbase with the right request parameters), you should first point the user agent to Spring...
